# Loop through cells of a range and convert to a hyperlink and change (Text To Display) to an ascending number per each row

Tags: vba, excel

I have used the below code Loop through cells of a range and convert to a hyperlink and change (Text To Display) to an ascending number per each row.
it works, but for the point of **ascending number** I have to use two loops (`r` and `i`).
I wish to replace these loops with column index with reference to range `rngFinal` as this answer by @FaneDuru [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76381224/loop-through-rows-of-a-table-on-outlook-and-change-text-to-display-to-an-ascen/76388178?noredirect=1#comment134757194_76388178)

[image]

[image]

```
Sub Convert_to_Hyperlink()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim rngFinal As Range, cel As Range, r As Variant, i As Long
    
    Set rngFinal = ws.Range("I2:K4")
    
    For Each r In rngFinal.Rows
     i = 0
      For Each cel In r.Cells
       If cel.Value <> "" Then
        i = i + 1
          ws.Hyperlinks.Add cel, _
          Address:=cel.Value, TextToDisplay:="Attach " & i
        End If
      Next cel
    Next r
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following code. Range column, which is relative to the sheet columns can be made relative to a specific range.  There is no need to iterate by rows:

```
Sub Convert_to_Hyperlink()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim rngFinal As Range, cel As Range
    
    Set rngFinal = ws.Range("I2:K4")
    
    For Each cel In rngFinal.cells
       If cel.Value <> "" Then
          ws.Hyperlinks.Add cel, _
          address:=cel.Value, TextToDisplay:="Attach " & cel.column - rngFinal.column + 1
        End If
    Next cel
   
End Sub
```

Comment: excellent, it works perfectly. Please how did you find the logic behind `cel.column - rngFinal.column + 1` ?

Comment: @Soma I found it many years before... Try `Debug.print rngFinal.Column`. It will return **the first column of the range**. Relative to the sheet, of course. Then, each cell returns the relative to sheet column, which can be converted in the range one in that simple way. I must confess that I did not understand what you meant by "my range columns" when we had a talk about the issue...